# Stop and Continue Looping of For Loop In Java

Tags: java, for-loop, wait

I have a project in which I am having a "for loop" iterating over an arraylist. I need to stop the iteration in between and continue again. I tried doing it by applying an "if else" condition in between but it didn't work.

I have an arraylist of size 2500 and I need the for loop to iterate 500 times and then wait and call a function and again continue looping and stop after the next 500 and so on.

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
int msgCount = 0;
ArrayList<JSONInput > saveArrayList = new ArrayList<JSONInput >();

for(JSONInput jsonInput: arrXMLString){          
    publisher.send(jsonInput);
    saveArrayList.add(jsonInput);

    if(msgCount<500){  // it will loop for 500 times and increment msgCount
        msgCount++;  
    } else {                              
        msgCount=0;
        SentService.sendArraylist(saveArrayList);  
        saveArrayList.clear(); 
    }
}
```

This is not working. The loop does not stop and when I debug it stops in the "else" condition but the loop does not wait for the condition to complete.

Comment: what you mean does not stop? you want to send first 500 elements of the list each time?

Comment: Look into `wait()` and `notify()`

Comment: Yes i nee to send 500 then stop for till the else condition then continue loop for next 500 and so on @JordiCastilla

Comment: try to explain what you expect the loop to do. I do not get the problem yet.

Comment: I have an arraylist i want arraylist to iterate for first 500 elements then wait then again continue loop for next 500 and wait again... Hope you got my problem ..@luksch

Comment: I cant make use of threads there so cant use wait and notify () @Trobbins

Comment: what do you mean by "wait"? is the SendArraylist method somehow async?

Comment: Do you know what threads are?

Comment: Oh okay, that's interesting. @luksch I believe they want to call a function from within the loop and pause the loop until they get a response. But without using threads..

Comment: @Trobbins yes you got my problem

Comment: in case sendArraylist starts an async task and you do need to wait for the response in the caller and you do not want to use proper messaging I don#t see another chance but polling for the expected result in the else block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have arraylist of size 2500 and i need for loop to iterate 500 times and then wait and call a function and again continue looping and stop after 500 and so on

Create a temporary List to add each item into. Use a for loop and check the index value of the loop - if this value is divisible by 500 call the necessary code.

```
//presuming arrXMLString is a List 
List<JSONInput> saveArrayList = new ArrayList<JSONInput>();
for ( int i = 0; i < arrXMLString.size(); i++ ){
    JSONInput jsonInput = arrXMLString.get(i);
    publisher.send(jsonInput);
    saveArrayList .add(jsonInput);
    if ( i % 500 == 0 && i > 0 ){
        SentService.sendArraylist(tempList);  
        saveArrayList .clear();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes something similar to this i am doing .. I have made a variable and incremented that..can you tell me why that is not working

Comment: @copeg, why you are creating the **tempList** outside for loop? you can just create it inside and save a call to clear()?

Comment: I am not iterating same arraylist and making change in that.There are two different arraylists

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you are actually asking, but my guess is that your call of `SentService.sendArraylist(saveArrayList)` does return before it consumes the `saveArrayList`, i.e. it is using Threads and your own code is not Thread safe. In order to circumvent this, you may use a pattern like indicated below.

**NOTE:** This might be complete bollocks, since I really don't know if that is indeed your problem...

```
int msgCount = 0;
ArrayList<JSONInput > saveArrayList = new ArrayList<JSONInput >();

for(JSONInput jsonInput: arrXMLString){          
    publisher.send(jsonInput);
    saveArrayList.add(jsonInput);

    if(msgCount<500){  // it will loop for 500 times and increment msgCount
        msgCount++;  
    } else {                              
        msgCount=0;
        SentService.sendArraylist(saveArrayList); 

        //poll for expected result
        while (Whatever you need to check){
           Thread.sleep(500); //depends on how long you expect async sendArraylist takes
        } 
        saveArrayList.clear(); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is almost correct;

```
... = new ArrayList<>(500);
```

would be better.

And after the loop one should not forget to sent the remainder:

```
if (!saveArrayList.isEmpty()) {
    SentService.sendArraylist(saveArrayList);
    saveArrayList.clear();
}
```